# Using Rails validations, how do I whitelist a phrase, e.g., "Learn Ruby"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `validates_presence_of :subject, inclusion: { in: %w( 'Learn Ruby' 'Learn Ruby on Rails'), message: "Please select a valid Subject" }`  Learn Ruby and Learn Ruby on Rails are examples of what I'm trying to do.

I've tried using single and double quotes without success.

I've also tried an array: `validates_presence_of :subject, inclusion: { in: ['Learn Ruby', 'Learn Ruby on Rails'], message: "Please select a valid Subject" }` without success.

I'm familiar with the [Phrasing gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/phrasing); however, installing it seems overkill.  (And, not having tried it, I'm not sure it will help here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing the old `validates_x_y` type methods with the Rails 3.x `validates` which is much more general purpose.

`validates_presence_of` is from the Rails 1.x era and can *only* deal with the presence of something. There's `validates_inclusion_of` as a counterpart, but the real answer is to use the `validates` call which can be configured to test for any number of things at once.

The notation for that is:

```
validates :subject,
  inclusion: {
    in: [
      'Learn Ruby',
      'Learn Ruby on Rails'
    ],
    message: "Please select a valid Subject"
  }
```

I've added some formatting as well to make what's going on more clear. Those one-liners can get really tangled.

If your introduction is using those old-style `validates_presence_of` methods it's out of date and you should look for a more recent version, or a better reference. As a note the official [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) is usually a great place to start.

Comment: tadman, thanks, dumb error on my part.  I copied the validations from an old project, hence the `validates_presence_of`  With `validates` and an array it works.  I'm accepting your answer; hopefully, it will help someone else.  There aren't any similar q&a's on SO

Answer (score 0):

How about ActiveModel [`validates_inclusion_of`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of)?

```
validates_inclusion_of :subject, in: ['Learn Ruby', 'Learn Ruby on Rails'], message: 'Please select a valid Subject'
```

Comment: That's the old way. `validates :subject, inclusion: [ ... ]` has been the style since at least Rails 3.x as per [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion).

Comment: @tadman didnt know that and there is nothing about that in the docs

Comment: I linked to the docs there in a quick edit to explain better.

Comment: @tadman Thats a link to the guide but a mean [`validates_presence_of`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of) and [`validates_inclusion_of`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_inclusion_of) docs

Comment: Those methods are defunct as the new `validates` method can do everything those individual methods used to do and more, so that's why they're no longer discussed.

Comment: @tadman I dont think these helper methods should be called "defunct" because then they would be depricated. And thats not the case. Just checked rails 5.2.0 docs and its there. [`validates`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates) more handy tho but I guess its more about personal preference

Comment: I'm saying "defunct" because they're not officially deprecated, but I have a feeling they will be soon. They're being maintained for backwards compatibility but it's highly probable that they'll start to generate deprecation warnings in the future.